# Connecting to mobile broadband without nm-applet

Tags: linux, mobile-broadband

I'm trying to connect to mobile internet using an NAS box. it's flashed to use conventional Linux instead of busybox. It doesn't have any video interface and has very little ram. I'm using this because it's less noisy/consumes less power.

nm-applet is pain because it doesn't have ncurses gui. Can I not get Network Manager to automatically connect to mobile broaband without any manual intervention via the applet?
It can and does automatically connect my Ethernet connection so why not mobile broadband?

I know in the applet you can tick automatically connect but the connection doesn't stay on once applet has closed down. Plus am the only one that knows Linux. It's a pain to be constantly harassed.